# output template error for an instruction when macthing sign_extend operand

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

While building a gcc cross compiler, I needed to add an instruction for type conversion of `short` to `int`.

So, I added an instruction which does `sign_extend` of the `short` operand to `int`.

I am cribbing from the `aarch64`'s .md file.
The template for the `aarch64` is:

```
(define_insn "*extend<SHORT:mode><GPI:mode>2_aarch64"
  [(set (match_operand:GPI 0 "register_operand" "=r,r")
    (sign_extend:GPI (match_operand:SHORT 1 "nonimmediate_operand" "r,m")))]
  ""
  "@
  sxt<SHORT:size>\t%<GPI:w>0, %w1
  ldrs<SHORT:size>\t%<GPI:w>0, %1"
  [(set_attr "type" "extend,load1")]
)
```

When compiling a code which needs such a conversion, (sum of an `int` and a `short` variables), `aarch64`'s final dump `insn` is:

```
(insn 9 8 10 (set (reg:SI 1 x1 [orig:73 D.2676 ] [73])
    (sign_extend:SI (mem/c:HI (plus:DI (reg/f:DI 31 sp)
                (const_int 10 [0xa])) [0 j+0 S2 A16]))) int+short.c:6 77 {*extendhisi2_aarch64}
  (nil))
```

And the assembler instruction is: `ldrsh    w1, [sp, 10]`

In my .md file I added:

```
(define_insn "extendhisi2"  
   [(set (match_operand:SI 0 "register_operand" "=r,r")
      (sign_extend:SI (match_operand:HI 1 "nonimmediate_operand" "r,m")))]
   ""
   "@
   sxth\t%0, %1
   ldrsh\t%0, %1"
)
```

The only difference is that my architecture is 32 bit, so I adapted the `mode` of the operands.

When compiling the same code, I am getting the compiler error:

```
int+short.c: In function ‘main’:
int+short.c:9:1: internal compiler error: output_operand: invalid expression as operand
```

and when I change the ***output template*** not to output the second operand (from

```
"@
sxth\t%0, %1
ldrsh\t%0, %1"
```

to

```
"@
sxth\t%0
ldrsh\t%0"
```

), the instruction is generated correctly (compiles without error): `ldrsh  r1`

The `insn` in the final dump is adequate:

```
(insn 9 8 10 (set (reg:SI 1 r1 [orig:39 D.1457 ] [39])
    (sign_extend:SI (mem/c:HI (plus:SI (reg/f:SI 30 FP)
                (const_int -6 [0xfffffffffffffffa])) [0 j+0 S2 A16]))) int+short.c:6 13 {extendhisi2}
 (nil))
```

So, my question is: what causes such an error when trying to output the second operand?
The correct instruction should be `ldrsh  r1, FP[-6]`.